# Image with Accordion Effect not align perfectly

Tags: html, css, reactjs, accordion

Here I have created a hover accordion effect using a list of images. So here I have created that container that aligns all the images in parallel, so all the images will be there with 20% width, and when hovered, it should pop up with 80% width. So here I have faced the problem that all the images will be shown there but are not showing. How to align with the display Flex Row format and show all the images in a row, and when it hovers, its pop-up code is given below

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const imageUrls = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581551-867e0b208bd1?q=80&w=1470&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1697219590638-d2db7748802e?q=80&w=1452&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581427-7c80ab60e3f3?q=80&w=1470&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="ctr-accordion">
        {imageUrls.map((imageUrl, index) => (
          <div className="tab">
            <img key={index} src={imageUrl} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and css is

```
.ctr-accordion {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  gap: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
.tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.tab img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.tab:hover img {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.tab:hover {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: You see the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M" icon?